# Ones as Pronoun Reference

Tags: pronouns

Take the following sentence:

> Are mathematically proficient students, or even mathematically brilliant students, always motivated?

Can *students* be replaced by *ones*?

> Are mathematically proficient students, or even mathematically brilliant ***ones***, always motivated?

My intuition says yes. If it is acceptable, does it make the first sentence unacceptable?

Comment: Yes it can, and no, it does not make the first sentence unacceptable. Both sound fine to my ears. If speaking the first sentence I think you would put more emphasis on *brilliant*.

Comment: [Dictionary.com #22](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ones)

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, and no, it's optional, not obligatory. The non-specific indefinite pronoun _one_ (plural _ones_, possessives _one's,_ pl poss _ones'_) can be used for any noun, including (and I think most commonly) nouns describing humans. But pronominalization is rarely required, except in syntactic constructions like tag questions, and indefinite pronominalization is never required, so both sentences are OK.

Comment: Go all the way, ie: Are mathematically proficient students, or even brilliant ones, always motivated?

Comment: You can replace absolutely every word in absolutely every sentence in absolutely every language. By your reasoning, that would make absolutely everything in all languages unacceptable.

Comment: _One_ may be subsituted for any non-specific indefinite noun phrase that is repeated in a sentence. Thus the ***second*** occurence of _students_ can become _ones_, but not the first; the first one is the antecedent of _ones_ and normally has to precede it.

Comment: @x-code That introduces potentially undesirable ambiguity between students who are *mathematically* brilliant, and those who are just brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct grammatically. In my opinion, the second sentence sounds better as it avoids repetition.

*One* is a pronoun ([indefinite pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun)), so use it just like any other. Usage of a regular pronoun (ex: "he" for "the man") is always optional. However, using a pronoun avoids repetition and makes the sentence sound better.

Comment: Both sentences are correct grammatically. In my opinion, the first sentence sounds better as it avoids the anticlimax of 'ones'.

Comment: I guess that's just a difference in opinions. We can agree on the fact that none of the sentences are "wrong", though.

Comment: And neither is significantly better.

Comment: Nice answer and advice. Actually though, this kind of "one" is not a pronoun. It is used as a proform, but it is actually a common Noun. This can be shown by that fact that it takes an /s/ suffix for plurals, and can be genitively inflected for case - and when it is, it takes an apostrophe. The "one" that *is* a pronoun is the "one" that we sometimes use to mean *a person* or the queen uses to mean *you*. As in: *One can't buy much for a fiver nowadays*